# rowwise iteration in r on a data table

Tags: r, data.table

```
library(quantmod)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
getSymbols("YHOO",src="google")
stock_dat=data.table(PerformanceAnalytics::
CalculateReturns(Cl(YHOO)[1:10],'discrete'))
stock_dat[,Price:=0]
stock_dat[1,2]=Cl(YHOO)[1]
stock_dat[,D:=(1+YHOO.Close)*shift(Price,1)]
```

The above code generates the below result:

```
 stock_dat
      YHOO.Close Price     D
 1:           NA 25.61    NA
 2:  0.048418586  0.00 26.85
 3:  0.033147114  0.00  0.00
 4:  0.006488825  0.00  0.00
 5: -0.012177650  0.00  0.00
 6:  0.040609137  0.00  0.00
 7:  0.017421603  0.00  0.00
 8:  0.008561644  0.00  0.00
 9: -0.005432937  0.00  0.00
10: -0.008193923  0.00  0.00
```

The YHOO.Close is assumed to be a simulated returns and i need to back out the prices from that. And i am using the first price as the base. The above code needs to ideally use the price in D from row 3.

```
nrowsDF <- nrow(stock_dat)

for(i in 2:nrowsDF){
  stock_dat[i,2]=(1+stock_dat[i,1,with=FALSE])*stock_dat[i-1,2,with=FALSE]
}
```

The above code solves the problem. But am looking for a more efficent way to do this, as i have to repeat this for over 5000 simulated return series

The below is the answer i actually need

```
stock_dat
      YHOO.Close Price
 1:           NA 25.61
 2:  0.048418586 26.85
 3:  0.033147114 27.74
 4:  0.006488825 27.92
 5: -0.012177650 27.58
 6:  0.040609137 28.70
 7:  0.017421603 29.20
 8:  0.008561644 29.45
 9: -0.005432937 29.29
10: -0.008193923 29.05
```

Comment: `shift(Price,1)` is 0 for all but the first entry.

Comment: Also the code you pasted doesn't run. You need: `stock_dat=data.table(PerformanceAnalytics::
                       CalculateReturns(Cl(YHOO[1:10]),'discrete'))`

Comment: @Imo The second entry needs to use the price in D

Comment: Is this supposed to calculate growth where `YHOO.Close` is the % change from row to row and `Price` is the base?  Also it would help if you pasted your desired result.

Comment: Is this what you want? `stock_dat[1:10,2]=Cl(YHOO)[1:10]` `stock_dat[,D:=(1+YHOO.Close)*shift(Price,1),]`. Also your desired result is already in `YHOO.Close`

Comment: Check out `head(Cl(YHOO),10)`

Comment: @Mike I just used this as an example to showcase what i need. Please assume that you dont have this data 'Cl(YHOO)[1:10]' except for Cl(YHOO)[1]. We have use the price in row1 to calculate the the price in row2 and the calculated price in row2  for row3 and so on. Hope this helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the cumulative product like this:

```
DT <- fread("      YHOO.Close Price     D
                     NA 25.61    NA
            0.048418586  0.00 26.85
            0.033147114  0.00  0.00
            0.006488825  0.00  0.00
           -0.012177650  0.00  0.00
            0.040609137  0.00  0.00
            0.017421603  0.00  0.00
            0.008561644  0.00  0.00
           -0.005432937  0.00  0.00
           -0.008193923  0.00  0.00")

DT[, res := Price[1] * c(1, cumprod(1 + YHOO.Close[-1]))]
#      YHOO.Close Price     D   res
# 1:           NA 25.61    NA 25.61
# 2:  0.048418586  0.00 26.85 26.85
# 3:  0.033147114  0.00  0.00 27.74
# 4:  0.006488825  0.00  0.00 27.92
# 5: -0.012177650  0.00  0.00 27.58
# 6:  0.040609137  0.00  0.00 28.70
# 7:  0.017421603  0.00  0.00 29.20
# 8:  0.008561644  0.00  0.00 29.45
# 9: -0.005432937  0.00  0.00 29.29
#10: -0.008193923  0.00  0.00 29.05
```

Comment: Thank you. Extremely simple and fast. I was wondering if it is possible to do the same exercise without the use of two columns, in the above example without the column 'Price' and 'D'.  For each column 'YHOO.CLose' get a 'res' as output (The above example has only one 'YHOO.CLose' )

Comment: Yes, of course. You only need the `YHOO.Close` columns (it would help if the first element was zero instead of `NA`) and corresponding starting prices. Then you can use `Map` within the data.table (or `lapply` if you have only one starting price).